# Values taken from the array do not appear

Tags: php

I generate a nested array into PHP using Javascript and its variables, which I send using hidden input. I wanted to capture what the generated the array and display it in the appropriate form on the page, I wrote the following script but it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

**PHP Array**

```
[section] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    ['sectionwidth'] => 525
                    ['sectionheight'] => 500
                    ['bg'] => eaeaea
                    ['sectioncolor'] => c0c0c0
                    ['input'] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    ['inputtext'] => pyk pyk
                                    ['inputwidth'] => 500
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    ['inputtext'] => cyk cyk
                                    ['inputwidth'] => 500
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    ['sectionwidth'] => 525
                    ['sectionheight'] => 500
                    ['bg'] => 222222
                    ['sectioncolor'] => ffffff
                    ['input'] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    ['inputtext'] => pam pam
                                    ['inputwidth'] => 500
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    ['inputtext'] => no no
                                    ['inputwidth'] => 500
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

**PHP Code**

```
foreach ($_POST['section'] as $sekcja) {
            echo '<div style="width: '.$sekcja['sectionwidth'].'px; height: '.$sekcja['sectionheight'].'px; background: #'.$sekcja['bg'].'; color: #'.$sekcja['sectioncolor'].';">';
            foreach ($sekcja['input'] as $input) {
                '<p style="width: '.$input['inputwidth'].'px;">'.$input['inputtext'].'</p>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
```

Comment: Can you describe the behavior you mention doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($_POST['section'] as $sekcja) {
            echo '<div style="width: '.$sekcja['sectionwidth'].'px; height: '.$sekcja['sectionheight'].'px; background: #'.$sekcja['bg'].'; color: #'.$sekcja['sectioncolor'].';">';
            foreach ($sekcja['input'] as $input) {
                echo '<p style="width: '.$input['inputwidth'].'px;">'.$input['inputtext'].'</p>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
```

You are missing an echo inside the foreach

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately its a not solution of my problem :/

Comment: PHP returns undefined index

Comment: Can you please print_r($input) inside the second loop and paste the response over here

Comment: I've found a solution, the problem was not on the PHP side, and on the Javascript side and generating dynamic variables, rather the syntax writing. Anyway, thank you beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($_POST['section'] as $sekcjda) {
      foreach($sekcjda as $sekcja){
            echo '<div style="width: '.$sekcja['sectionwidth'].'px; height: '.$sekcja['sectionheight'].'px; background: #'.$sekcja['bg'].'; color: #'.$sekcja['sectioncolor'].';">';
            foreach ($sekcja['input'] as $input) {
              echo '<p style="width: '.$input['inputwidth'].'px;">'.$input['inputtext'].'</p>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
}
```

You are missing an echo inside the foreach and also section return array of array's so you need another loop to get sectionheight and all other things